Admonitions blocks in org mode
I would like to have admonition blocks in my org-mod document which have aesthetic styling and folding similar to Logseq (Screenshot below). I would like to have these visible right within emacs not in an exported HTML.
Are there any good themes/packages which have styled structural blocks (#+BEGIN_QUOTE, #+BEGIN_CENTER etc...). I'm looking for something that add functionality that displays blocks like admonitions individually and distinguishes each of them (like in the below screenshot).
If not themes, are there any existing open-source configurations which help in setting up something like this?

Note that I'm looking for a solution that works in the GUI-Emacs, not in any export

Logseq Screenshot Example


just found org-special-block-extras from this reddit post which is 2 years old. Curious if there are any more.

Question encourages opinion-based answers, so should be deleted. Consider posing it at a discussion site such as Reddit instead.

I found this issue recently logged in emacs archives which requests to allow adding "Admonition blocks" in org mode.
Looks like this is being planned right now, but I don't see any status or progress mentioned anywhere.
